# highcharts gapsize in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, highcharts

To plot a set of values over a time line I'm using Highstock (Highchart would be the same).

With Highstock, it's possible to set the attribute **gapSize** to mark a a 'gap' (a blank hole of missing data) if more than X intervals are missing.

The 'interval' is calculated automatically as the smallest interval in the serie.

If the dataset doesn't contain always equally spaced intervals the result is unpredictable and as shown in this example, it can be full of gaps:

https://jsfiddle.net/ptysyo4p/5/

```
series : [{
            data : data,
            type: 'areaspline',
            fillOpacity: .35,
            gapSize: 5,       <-- The responsible
```

It would be Ideal to set the size of the interval manually or directly setting gapSize as a *time interval* instead as a *number OF intervals*. Is it possible?

UPDATE:

By looking in the code I think it is **closestPointRange**(https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/search?p=1&q=closestPointRange&utf8=%E2%9C%93). Any ideas if I can set it at will without breaking anything?

Comment: Instead of making assumptions, tell exactly what you intent to achieve. Do you or don't you want gaps, if yes how to you want them to appear and where?

Comment: Yes I want to see the gaps but only if the distance between two points is greater than a specific amount of time that I can set

Comment: UPDATE: A valid answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119238/show-gap-of-missing-data-with-highstock