# Show gap of missing data with Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using Highstock to chart a sorted time serie: `[[timestamp, value], ...]`

The datasource is sampled at irregular intervals. As result the distances between two points (in the time axis) varies.

If two adjacent points are separated for more than 5 minutes I want to show a gap in the chart.

Using the `gapSize` option doesn't work, because it doesn't allows to specify the 'size' of the gap as a function of time.

Showing gaps is already a part of Highstock, I just need a way to specify it as a fixed amount of time (5 minutes). Ideas?

Btw, beside that the plot works great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a slightly unclean way to "manipulate" `gapSize` to work so that it's value is the amount of milliseconds required to create a gap.

```
(function (H) {
    // Wrap getSegments to change gapSize functionality to work based on time (milliseconds)
    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'getSegments', function (proceed) {
        var cPR = this.xAxis.closestPointRange;
        this.xAxis.closestPointRange = 1;

        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        this.xAxis.closestPointRange = cPR;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

This utilizes that `gapSize` is only used within the `getSegments` function ([see source](http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js)), and it works based on the `closestPointRange` of the axis. It wraps the `getSegments`, sets `closestPointRange` to `1`, calls the original method and then resets `closestPointRange` to its original value.

With the code above you could do gaps for 5 minutes like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        gapSize: 300000 // 5 minutes in milliseconds
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/keyxo45x/) of how it may work.

Answer (score 2):

[Halvor Strand function wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30121952/2961401) did not work for me as long as getSegments is not part of highstock [source code](http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js) anymore to calculate that gap. Anyway, you can find an approximation to solve the problem combining [this other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35342547/2961401) and the previows answer like this:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'gappedPath', function(proceed) {
    var gapSize = this.options.gapSize,
      xAxis = this.xAxis,
      points = this.points.slice(),
      i = points.length - 1;

    if (gapSize && i > 0) { // #5008

      while (i--) {
        if (points[i + 1].x - points[i].x > gapSize) { // gapSize redefinition to be the real threshold instead of using this.closestPointRange * gapSize
          points.splice( // insert after this one
            i + 1,
            0, {
              isNull: true
            }
          );
        }
      }
    }
    return this.getGraphPath(points);
  });
}(Highcharts))
```

setting gapSize in plotOptions to the desired size (in ms) like Halvor said:

```
plotOptions: {
  line: {
    gapSize: 300000 // 5 minutes in milliseconds
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this and is spending hours trying to figure out why gapSize is not working like me. Make sure your time series data is sorted, only then will the gaps appear in the graph.

Another issue I ran into was my data series was in this format

```
[
      {x: 1643967900000, y: 72},
      {x: 1643967600000, y: 72},
      {x: 1643967300000, y: 72}
]
```

However this does not seem to work with gapSize and needs to be in the format below

```
[
      [1643967900000, 72],
      [1643967600000, 91],
      [1643967300000, 241]
]
```